# how to post multiple forms to same route using SlimFramework?

Tags: php, forms, routes, slim

I have the following view (main.php) that contains two separate forms that post to the same route:

```
<form class="form" id="first_form" action="{{ urlFor('main.post') }}" method="post">
    // form data
</form>

<form class="form" id="second_form" action="{{ urlFor('main.post') }}" method="post">
    // form data
</form>
```

Here is the route logic that renders that view and also post the form data:

```
$app->get('/main', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('main.php');
})->name('main');

$app->post('/main', function() use ($app) {
    // do something
})->name('main.post');
```

Now within my `$app->post` method, I would like to differentiate between which form was submitted and do separate logic accordingly, like so:

```
$app->post('/main', function() use ($app) {
    if(first form was submitted) {
       // do something
    } else if(second form was submitted){
       // do something else
    }
})->name('main.post');
```

**Does what I am trying to accomplish need to utilize Middleware? if not, what logic do i need to implement to accomplish this seemingly simple task**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include an hidden field in your form which indicates which form was submitted.

```
<form class="form" id="first_form" action="{{ urlFor('main.post') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="which" value="first_form">
    // form data
</form>

<form class="form" id="second_form" action="{{ urlFor('main.post') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="which" value="second_form">
    // form data
</form>
```

Then in your route check the value of `which` input.

```
$app->post('/main', function() use ($app) {
    $which = $app->request()->post('which')
    if ('first_form' === $which) {
        // do something
    } else if ('second_form' === $which){
        // do something else
    }
})->name('main.post');
```

Comment: you know... sometimes as a dev, its that natural fixation with thinking complex that holds us back. so simple, thanks mate.